# I'm getting an implicit declaration error only when using -std=c99

Tags: c, gcc, c99, ncurses

For some reason, -std=c99 is keeping gcc from seeing the declaration of function wborder_set() (which lives in `<curses.h>`)

```
#include <curses.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  initscr(); // start ncurses
  cbreak();  // don't wait for lf to getch
  noecho();  // don't copy entered characters
  nonl();    // use /r/l
  clear();   // clear the screen!

  setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");

  int ySize, xSize;
  getmaxyx(stdscr, ySize, xSize);
  WINDOW *upperWin = newwin(ySize, xSize, 0, 0);

  // magic utf encodings for window border
  wborder_set( upperWin, "\u1234", "\u1234", "\u1234", "\u1234",
           "\u1234", "\u1234", "\u1234", "\u1234" );
  wrefresh(upperWin);
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling with `gcc test.c -lncursesw -o cursestest` works fine! If, however, I compile with

`gcc test.c -std=c99 -lncursesw -o cursestest`

it replies,

`cursescurses.c: In function ‘main’:
cursescurses.c:18:7: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘wborder_set’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
       wborder_set( upperWin, "\u1234", "\u1234", "\u1234", "\u1234",`

which leads me to believe that I can't trust that it is properly linking wborder_set.

Why would this happen?

Comment: aha! 

"The following EXTENDED XSI Curses calls in support of wide (multibyte) characters are not yet implemented: ... wborder_set()..."

so even though the function is defined in the man page, it doesn't actually exist. d'oh.

Comment: You have to define `_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED` before including any header to expose the declaration.

Comment: Is this on Linux? I find that on Linux, options like -std=c99 tend to restrict header files to minimal c99 mode, and disable any possible extensions such as various POSIX features.

Comment: I am on linux, yes. Also, I tried defining `_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED`, that didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was that I had included the wrong version of `<curses.h>`. The function `wborder_set` implements unicode and needed the unicode/wide char extension of the ncurses library, which I included with `#include <ncursesw/curses.h>`. With this substitution, the program compiled as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Defining `_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED` would help, but Linux (like most systems) has pitfalls in the form of extensions which conflict with the standards, and differing interpretations of the standards.  So... for Linux, the universal band-aid for this is to start by defining `_GNU_SOURCE` (which turns on the appropriate X/Open defines as an afterthought).

If your ncurses configuration includes a [reasonably current](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NEWS.html#t20150221) `ncursesw5-config` script it will add that `-D` option.

Answer (score 1):

Your `<curses.h>` doesn't seem to include a prototype for the function. The rules changed in C99: using functions without a declaration is not allowed anymore. Before, they would be assumed to return `int`.

This has nothing to do with linking, but this a question about the compiler expecting a certain return type for a function.

Comment: the function `wborder_set` is declared in curses.h; can I ignore that warning then and expect it to work as in c89? do I need to copy the prototype from curses.h into my code file???

Comment: @sig_seg_v, no, if the code is as you have given here, the compiler doesn't find a declaration for the function. You should not ignore such warnings, they indicate that something in your tool chain is wrong.